# Should I use shareReplay as the last operator?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I develop an Angular 9 application and I don't understand how to use `shareReplay` operator together with other operators. I did something like the following:

```
if (!this.cache[key]) {
  this.cache[key] = this.http.get(...).pipe(
    shareReplay(1),
    flatMap(...),
    map(...),
    reduce(...)
  );
}
return this.cache[key];
```

After this my application stucked with 100% CPU usage. When I changed it to:

```
if (!this.cache[key]) {
  this.cache[key] = this.http.get(...).pipe(
    flatMap(...),
    map(...),
    reduce(...),
    shareReplay(1)
  );
}
return this.cache[key];
```

it seems to work fine. Is it necessary to use the `shareReplay` operator as the last one? Where this high CPU usage comes from?

Edit: a more detailed code snippet:

```
this.http.get(...).pipe(
  // I would like to avoid several same http calls
  shareReplay(1),
  // I would like to flatten an array of objects that comes from backend
  flatMap(option => option),
  // I need to map all objects to a format that is acceptable by some library
  map(option => ({
    value: option.key,
    label: option.value
  })),
  // I must reduce it back to an array of the new objects
  reduce((acc: { value: string; label: string }[], option) => {
    acc.push(option);
    return acc;
  }, [])
);
```

Comment: Kindly share the internal functions of these operators.

Comment: Also, comment out reason for each of these operator.

Comment: @abhaytripathi See my explanation, please.

Comment: flatMap/map/reduce calls look misplaced on the example code. Looks like the intention is to performa some array manipulations. Instead, you split an array into multiple emitted values and use rxjs operators to transform the resulting stream.
Probably should be `.pipe(map(options => options.flat().map(...)), shareReplay(1)`. Note that `reduce` is no longer needed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The position of the `share` operator in the pipe is important, because it determines how many subscribers will subscribe to operators that come before `share`.

Take the following example:

```
const interval$ = interval(1000).pipe(
  tap(() => console.log("Interval Triggered")
);

interval$.subscribe();
interval$.subscribe();
```

What you'll see is that we get two console message every second. That makes sense, because in RxJS, every subscriber ("consumer") will cause the factory to create a new "producer" (here a `setInterval`). In this case - there is no `share` operator - every subscriber will go up the operator chain and subscribe to the previous operator - until we subscribe to `interval` twice.

Now, let's take a look at `share`:

```
const interval$ = interval(1000).pipe(
  tap(() => console.log("Interval Triggered"),
  share()
);

interval$.subscribe();
interval$.subscribe();
```

With this version, we'll only get one message per second. Why?

Because `share` won't subscribe to it's source as long as there is one active subscriber. So, we subscribe to `share()` twice, but `share()` only subscribes to `interval` once.

If we switch positions, we get a different result:

```
const interval$ = interval(1000).pipe(
  share(),
  tap(() => console.log("Interval Triggered"),
);

interval$.subscribe();
interval$.subscribe();
```

In this case, we subscribe to `tap` twice - and those two `tap` operators subscribe to `share` twice. That's why we get two console messages per second.

As a rule of thumb, you'll most likely want your `share` at the end of your pipe, as this will cause the operators that come before `share` to be subscribed to only once.

---

To explain your CPU consumption: I suspect that you subscribe very often to this Observable - with `share` not being the last operator, this means that you'll resubscribe to `flatMap` etc. over and over again.

Comment: Great explanation! That is exactly what I was looking for, but couldn't find.